# Uploading file using requests python giving 500 error

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

```
try:
    request_url = http://sandbox.api.hmhco.com/v1/documents
    with open("C:\\Users\\Animesh\\Downloads\\assignment_4.pdf", "rb") as f:
        files = {
            "file": f
        }
        r = requests.post(request_url, files=files)
        r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()
except exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(-1)
```

This gives a 500 status error. I used logging to get what is being sent:

```
send: 
POST /v1/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: sandbox.api.hmhco.com
Vnd-HMH-Api-Key: some_api_key
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 56926
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Authorization: some_access_token
--e11c78c0aeeb4cafa9837388ab386660
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="assignment_4.pdf"
%PDF-1.5\n%\xc7\xec\x8f\xa2\n5.......afa9837388ab386660--'

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n'
header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Vnd-HMH-Api-Key
header: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
header: Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 05:21:58 GMT
header: Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
header: X-Application-Context: palantir:8070
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Connection: keep-alive
500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://sandbox.api.hmhco.com/v1/documents
```

But the corresponding cURL command works:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Vnd-HMH-Api-Key:some_api_key" -H "accepts:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:some_access_token" "http://sandbox.api.hmhco.com/v1/documents" -F file=@"C:\Users\Animesh\Downloads\assignment_4.pdf"
```

The verbose out gives:

```
> POST /v1/documents HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: sandbox.api.hmhco.com
> Accept: */*
> Vnd-HMH-Api-Key:some_api_key
> accepts:application/json
> Authorization:some_access_token
> Content-Length: 56982
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------20b5cc23cfa6d1d4
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Vnd-HMH-Api-Key
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, api_key, x-mashery-debug, Authorization, authCurrentDateTime, Content-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, api_key, x-mashery-debug, Authorization, authCurrentDateTime, Content-Type
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 05:28:40 GMT
< ETag: "e421273e09891349ef4808ca5677345c"
< P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Status: 200 OK
< User-Info: {"iss":"https://identity.api.hmhco.com","aud":"http://www.hmhco.com","iat":1451323840,"sub":"cn\u003dSauron Baraddur,uid\u003dsauron,uniqueIdentifier\u003dab1e436e-8177-4139-8e2d-52a6f7a8be27,dc\u0
3d1","http://www.imsglobal.org/imspurl/lis/v1/vocab/person":["Instructor"],"client_id":"ef5f7a03-58e8-48d7-a38a-abbd2696bdb6.hmhco.com","exp":1451409840}
< X-Application-Context: palantir:8070
< X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
< X-Request-Id: a0078f7f5daf804affb98de6947170ca
< X-Runtime: 0.066617
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Content-Length: 452
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{"content_type":"application/pdf","created_at":"2015-12-29T00:28:40-05:00","file_tmp":"1451366920-13680-2938/assignment_4.pdf","original_filename":"assignment_4.pdf","secure_token":"7f395da4-5ccf-41a6-86a3-16a5
af0de79","size":56774,"updated_at":"2015-12-29T00:2 ......
```

This gives response code 200 and response body as a json:

```
{
  "content_type": "application/pdf",
  "created_at": "2015-12-28T14:13:25-05:00",
  "file_tmp": "1451330005-13680-5506/assignment_4.pdf",
  "original_filename": "assignment_4.pdf",
  "secure_token": "9546cf79-0b00-4454-b577-6bdc8ddd7315",
  "size": 56774,
  "updated_at": "2015-12-28T14:13:25-05:00", ......
```

Comment: You are sending the wrong content type with your requests call.

Answer (score 0):

Change line which sends post request to:

```
r = requests.post(request_url, files=files, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Because in sample above curl making `post` with `'content-type': 'application/json'` and everything goes well and your python requests isn't. Setting content-type in python code should fix your issue.